# how to appear the fields of a object based on the custom picklist value (picklist created in page) selection in visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist, rerender, actionsupport

**Apex:**

```
public class TestPageCon {
    public String picklistval1 {get;set;}
    public String picklistval2 {get;set;}
    public List<object1> object1List{get;set;}
    public List<object2> Object2List{get;set;}
    public string selectedValue{get;set;}

    public TestPageCon() {
        object1List=new List<object1>();
        Object2List=new list<object2>();
    }

    // input1 & Input2

    public List<SelectOption> getObjectValue1(){
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Object1.District__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        }       
        return options;
    }


    public List<SelectOption> getObjectvalue2() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = object1.mandal__c.getDescribe();
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

        for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
        }       

        return options;
    }

    public void dosearch() {
        if(selectedValue=='picklist1') {
            victimList = [Select First_Name__c, Name,state__c,District__c,mandal__c,Village__c from object1 Where District__c =: picklistval1 and mandal__c=:picklistval2]; //change according to your criteria
        }
    }

    public void dosearch2() {        
        if(selectedValue=='picklist1') {       
            farmList=[select Name,state__c,District__c,mandal__c,Village__c from object2 Where District__c =: picklistval1 and mandal__c=:picklistval2];
        }
    }
}
```

**Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="TestPageCon">
<apex:form >
  <apex:pageblock >
      <!--code for list of objects:-->
       <apex:pageBlockSection >
           <apex:outputLabel >Select the object name:</apex:outputLabel>
         <apex:selectList value="{!selectedValue}">

          <apex:selectOption itemLabel="--None--" itemvalue=""></apex:selectOption>
          <apex:selectOption itemLabel="picklist1" itemValue="picklist1" onclick="DisplayFields();"></apex:selectOption>
          <apex:selectOption itemLabel="picklist2" itemValue="picklist2"></apex:selectOption>
           </apex:selectList>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>

      <!--Code for Object1 object:-->

  <apex:actionFunction name="dosearchaction" action="{!dosearch}" reRender="showObject1"/>
      <apex:pageBlockSection id="victFields">

          <apex:selectList id="pick1" value="{!picklistval1}" size="1" required="true" >
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!ObjectValue1}"/>
          </apex:selectList>

          <apex:selectList id="pick2" value="{!picklistval2}" size="1" required="true" onchange="dosearchaction();" >
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!Objectvalue2}"/>
          </apex:selectList>

      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:pageBlockSection id="showObject1">
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!object1List}" var="item">
              <apex:column value="{!item.State__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.District__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Mandal__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Village__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Name}"/>
                            <apex:column value="{!item.First_Name__c}"/>

          </apex:pageblockTable>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
      <apex:actionFunction name="dosearchaction" action="{!dosearch2}" reRender="showFarm"/>

             <apex:pageBlockSection id="showObject2">
          <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Object2List}" var="item">
              <apex:column value="{!item.State__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.District__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Mandal__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Village__c}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!item.Name}"/>

          </apex:pageblockTable>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>


  </apex:pageblock>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: You should add a little more details about where do you want to show the fields, which is the controlling picklist?

Comment: I want to show the fields of object in Page, Based on the picklist selection in line no.9 in page which are objects names. Then i select the picklistval1 and picklistval2 in UI, based on that qurey need to pass and diplay result .

Comment: Please elaborate. It's not clear.

Comment: @RavindarAdmin what exactly the issue is?

Comment: I want to display all the objects records in a page. Here picklists are object names. When i select object name some dependent  picklist fields(State, Mandal,district & mandal) of that objects should be appear on the UI , Then we can select the fields. Based on this selection records show display.   How to achieve this??